# Creating a Java project using an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently working on creating an Eclipse plugin. I have used `JFace` dialogs for users to put in certain details. When the user clicks `finish`, the Java project should be created automatically. How do I go about implementing that project creation?

Comment: There are various tutorials around for this such as [this](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial:_Creating_Eclipse_Java_Projects_Programmatically)

Comment: many thanks for directing me to the guide! Will go through!

Comment: Hi, Can you please have a look at the below question I posted.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003152/how-to-add-codes-to-java-classes-from-eclipse-plugin